# Loop sets color of the wrong object (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, i have a Grid Layout Group, which contains buttons. Each button represents one level a player can choose to start. When i load the scene, in which the player has to choose the level, i want to disable and recolor all buttons that represent locked levels.
I am doing that with the following code:

```
public Button[] levelButtons;
int levelReached = 1;
for (int i = levelReached; i < levelButtons.Length; i++) {
        levelButtons[i].interactable = false;
        levelButtons[i].image.color = Color.red;
}
```

For some reason, he always recolors the first button (levelButton[0]), but changes the interactability on all other buttons (levelButton[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ89y.png) to levelButton[levelButton.length]). 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ89y.png)

Why does Unity behave like that and how can i recolor the correct buttons?

I can't seem to find a solution for my problem and haven't found any relevant threads. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type is levelButtons?

Comment: It is an array.(public Button[] levelButtons;) Added to the initial post for clarity.

Comment: Then this is not real code. Button has no property `image` it would be `Image`. But that doesn't help. I just thought, that it might be a special implementation that references other objects of its kind or anything similar ...

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved it. I was under the impression, that button.image equals button.GetComponent<Image>(). The following code does what i want it to do:
 `levelButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;`
The behaviour of the original code is still strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would be correct:

```
public Button[] levelButtons;
int levelReached = 1;
for (int i = levelReached; i < levelButtons.Length; i++) {
        levelButtons[i].interactable = false;
        levelButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
}
```